# Primefaces 5.3 Calendar datetime pattern not working

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

In my app I am using Primefaces 5.3. I have problems with calendar pattern attribute. When I initialize the pattern by `dd/MM/yyyy` format, it is working properly and I can select and change the calendar date. When I change the pattern to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`, calendar component shows the date format but cannot be selected or changed.

Below is the calendar component that I used:

```
<p:calendar value="#{myBean.startDate}" showOn="button"
    locale="tr" showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true"
    id="startDate" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
</p:calendar>
```

In the backing bean the calendar component is initialized by java.util.date.
Changing format to datetime as above, there is an error in Javascript Console as below:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.jqEl.datetimepicker is not a function

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Your calendar component looks fine to me, and java.util.date should also work fine with this component. The only reason I could think of is jsf configuration or jQuery vs Primefaces library conflict. Did you explicitly add them?
Try to remove all **redundant** imports in this .xhtml or its parent like
`<h:outputScript ... />`

Comment: I have removed all the output script except the following one: **<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>**. If I remove it then "datepicker is not a function" error is thrown.